# How to remove an element in the list that has the same string but lower startDate

Tags: c#, linq

How to remove an element in the list that has the same string but lower startDate.Time?

Let's say you have a list that looks like this:

```
Datetime Date        String Name
07.06.2019 10:16:00, Test 
07.06.2019 11:16:00, Test 
07.06.2019 12:16:00, Test 
07.06.2019 13:16:00, Test 
07.06.2019 18:16:00, Test1 
07.06.2019 19:16:00, Test1 
07.06.2019 20:16:00, Test1 
07.06.2019 21:16:00, Test1 
07.06.2019 22:16:00, Test2 
07.06.2019 23:16:00, Test2
```

Given that the `DateTime.Date` is identical, I want to keep only the `DateTime.Date` that has the latest timestamp for each string in the list.

How can I achieve this?

My implementation :

```
List.OrderByDescending(x => x.Datetime).GroupBy(x => 
x.Datetime.Date).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
```

But this doesn't consider that the string should be different as if Test and test1 have the same `Datetime.Date` value, but the Test string has a later timestamp, then it would remove the Test1 element, which is not desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it via using Max;

```cs
var result = List.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                .Select(i => new MyList { Name = i.Key, DateTime = i.Max(j => j.DateTime).Date })
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the class with DateTime and string properties looks like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Then the LINQ which u can use is something like this:

```
var newList = List.GroupBy(l => l.Text).Select(g => new MyClass { Text = g.Key, Date = g.Max(i => i.Date)}).ToList();
```

This will give you a filtered list as per your requirement.

Comment: well this is pretty much my answer =)

Comment: @ilkerkaran great :) we think the same way! :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you said you wanted to get the latest on each date for each `Name`, I would suggest:

```
var ans = list.GroupBy(i => new { i.Date.Date, i.Name }).Select(ig => ig.OrderByDescending(i => i.Date.TimeOfDay).First()).ToList();
```